# $el.append not working in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

```
    console.log('Loaded inedx.js-->');
console.log(jQuery);
(function($){
    console.log('In immediate block');
  //Create new tweet view
   var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: function(){
        return {
          name    : 'defaultName',
          status  : 'default status'
       }
      }
    });

   var TweetList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model :Tweet
   });

   var TweetView = Backbone.View.extend({
      model : new Tweet(),
      tagName : 'div',
      initialize : function(){
         this.template = _.template($('#tweet-template').html());
      },
      render : function() {
          this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));          
          return this;
      }
   });

  var tweets = new TweetList();    
  var TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model : tweets,
    tagName : 'div',
    el : $('#allTweetContainer'),
    initialize: function(){
      this.model.on('add',this.render,this);      
    },    
    render : function(){
      var self = this;      
      _.each(this.model.toArray(),function(tweet,i){                   
          self.$el.append((new TweetView({model:tweet})).render().$el.html());
      });
      return this;
    }

  });

    $(document).ready(function (){

       tweets.add(new Tweet({
          status : 'status1',
          author : 'author1'
       }));
       var tweet = new Tweet({
          status : 'status1-----',
          author : 'author1-------'
       });
       //console.log(new TweetView());
       //$('#allTweetContainer').append( _.template($('#tweet-template').html(),tweet.toJSON()));

       tweets.add(new Tweet({
          status : 'status2',
          author : 'author2'
       }));
       tweets.add(new Tweet({
          status : 'status3',
          author : 'author3'
       }));
       tweets.add(new Tweet({
          status : 'status4',
          author : 'author4'
       }));
        var tweetApp = new TweetsView();
       tweetApp.render();

       console.log(tweets.toJSON());    
    });   
})(jQuery);
```

I am not able to render TweetsView.
Instead of : `self.$el.append`
When I used : `$('#allTweetContainer').append
it worked. But ideally it should work with self.$el.append. 
I believe there must be something extra needs to be done to get proper $el which should be a jQuery variable pointing to the given el.
Any pointers would really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tweets` is a collection so you should say `collection: tweets` instead of `model: tweets` and then `this.collection` instead of `this.model` inside the view's code. Also, don't bother with `_.each(this.collection.toArray(), ...)`, collections have some [Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) mixed in so you can just say `this.collection.each(function(tweet, i ) { ... }, this)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare el as string and not as jQuery selector. So your TweetsView should look like this:

```
var TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model : tweets,
  tagName : 'div',
  el : '#allTweetContainer',
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.on('add',this.render,this);      
  },    
  render : function(){
    var self = this;      
    _.each(this.model.toArray(),function(tweet,i){                   
      self.$el.append((new TweetView({model:tweet})).render().$el.html());
    });
    return this;
  }
});
```

when appending the TweetView to TweetsView, you could also do this:

```
_.each(this.model.toArray(),function(tweet,i){                   
  self.$el.append((new TweetView({model:tweet})).render().el);
});
```

Comment: `el : $('#allTweetContainer')` is okay, Backbone will unwrap the jQuery object on its own. But, `#allTweetContainer` probably isn't in the DOM when `TweetsView` is created so the real problem is a standard missing `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper. Switching to a string selector as you're suggesting also works.